# Flutter avoiding resize screen when i have TextFormField into PageView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

in this simplified code i have two `TextFormField` into one of flutter `PageView` pages, that they are into another class which that extended from `Container`, not any `Scaffold`, now when i click into one of this `TextFormFields`, resizeToAvoidBottom* don't work in my code

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ThemeManager>(builder: (context, theme, child) {
      return Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          backgroundColor: theme.accentColor,
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          body: NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
            onNotification: (overScroll) {
              overScroll.disallowGlow();
              return false;
            },
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 50,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          BuildLoginHeaderScreen(theme: theme),
                          Expanded(
                            child: PageView(
                              controller: _pageController,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                ... // contains two TextFormFields
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some code that can help us actually reproduce the error you're facing? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can go around using `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` by wrapping appropriate part of your code with `SingleChildScrollView`. For example

```
child: SingleChildScrollView( 
      child: Column(
               mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
               children: <Widget>[
                    BuildLoginHeaderScreen(theme: theme),
                    Expanded(
                        child: PageView(
                             controller: _pageController,
                             children: <Widget>[
                                ... // contains two TextFormFields
                              ],
                            ),
                     ),
              ],
      ),

),
```

This will prevent pixel overflow when the keyboard reduces the view area.